# Is it possible to kill full health opponents with a HE grenade?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is it possible to kill a full health (no armor) player with a single grenade? Does it make a difference if the grenade, let's say, explodes at a certain height?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/HE_grenade#Properties) a grenade can do a maximum of 98 damage to an unarmored enemy, and 57 to an armored one.

However throwing a grenade at an enemy's head will do 2 damage to them, therefore you can one shot someone with no armor by hitting them in the head with the grenade before it explodes near them. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbcV6Vaqv94) is a video demonstrating this.